# How to show the complete number on the Y-axis in Google Chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Chart to display a bar chart.  Please see the screen shot below.  Problem is, the highest number on the y-axis is always getting chopped off.  In the screenshot, the highest number is supposed to be 55; but, as you can see, only the lower portion of 55 is showing.  I have tried changing the height of my div and changing the height of the chart.  They didn't solve the problem.  I have also tried changing the max value of the y-axis but that does not solve the problem in the sense that the highest number would get chopped off (for example, for the chart in my screen shot, if I were to change the max value to 60, it is true that 55 would show completely but 60 would be chopped off).

How can I show the complete number on the highest value on y-axis in Google Charts?

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["", ""],
            ["Col_1", <?php echo $col1Count; ?>],
            ["Col_2", <?php echo $col2Count; ?>],
            ["Col_3", <?php echo $col3Count; ?>],
            ["Col_4", <?php echo $col4Count; ?>] 
        ]);
     

      var options = {
        width: 720,
        height: 550,
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        vAxis: { 
            viewWindow: {
                min: 5,
                max: 55
            },
            ticks: [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55]
 
        }
        
      };

      // Instantiate and draw the chart.
      
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('myChart'));
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('myChart')).then(function(canvas) {
          // console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
          //document.getElementById('myChart').appendChild(canvas);
           
           jQuery.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
              url: 'https://myURL.com/saveimage.php',
              data: {
                 // send image string as data
                imgstr: canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
               },
               success: function(response) {
                  alert(response);
               }
           });
           
          });
        });
    }
```

[image: Please see the highest number on Y-axis]

Comment: is it possible the chart is hidden when drawn and shown later?

Comment: Can you post your code for how you created this chart?

Comment: @dlaliberte sure, just did

Answer (score 0):

The material Bar chart has far fewer options than the classic charts.  I suspect that if you add a title, even if it is just a space character, that will reserve enough space above the chart to show the topmost axis tick label without truncation.